# Anomaly with System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (10060)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, websocket

Im making a software on C# with two-sided socket connection. Client opens a socket on this PC and starts listening to commands from server, when he receives and processes a command, it returns a response.
So that the server can send the message to the client, the client does port-forwarding on its router. And another thing is that the software makes multithreading tasks on client-side.
So the problem is that the client receives and responds to all server messages in the general part of the program, but when he starts branching out into tasks, client receives and responds on the first message, but when server sends the second one, the following error occurs:
System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. {ip}:{port}. This error throws on the server part.
Its very strange, because client reacts normally to all messages in the general part. Port-forwarding made on the client's router, firewall disabled.
Server-side code:

```
IPAddress ipAddr2 = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
IPEndPoint localEndPoint2 = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr2, 42762);
listener2 = new Socket(ipAddr2.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
Socket clientSocket = null;
try
{
    listener2.Bind(localEndPoint2);
    listener2.Listen(1000);
    while (true)
    {
        clientSocket = listener2.Accept();
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[8192];
        string data2 = null;
        int numByte = clientSocket.Receive(bytes);
        data2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, numByte);
        //if (data2.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
        //    break;
        switch (data2.Split('!')[0])
        {
            case "mes":
                Console.WriteLine(data2.Substring(4));
                messageSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Success"); break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        int byteSent = clientSocket.Send(messageSent);
        clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        clientSocket.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e3.ToString());
}
```

Client-side code:

```
IPAddress ipAddr2 = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
IPEndPoint localEndPoint2 = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr2, 42762);
Socket listener2 = new Socket(ipAddr2.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
ConsoleWriteLine(f1, "<< " + DateTime.Now + " || Device operation starts || Connection is in progress >>");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
var list = f1.ip_list;
Task[] tasks = new Task[list.Count];
Console.WriteLine("list.Count - " + tasks.Length);
ConsoleWriteLine(f1, "<< " + DateTime.Now + " || Starting >>"); //server can see it
ConsoleWriteLine(f1, "<< " + DateTime.Now + " || 1 >>"); //server can see it
ConsoleWriteLine(f1, "<< " + DateTime.Now + " || 2 >>"); //server can see it
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
{
    int taskIndex = i;
    string deviceIp = list[taskIndex];
    ConsoleWriteLine(f1, "<< " + DateTime.Now + " || 3 >>"); //server can see it
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Device(f1, list[taskIndex], taskIndex));
}

private static void Device(TestClass f1, string deviceIp, int taskIndex)
{
ConsoleWriteLine(f1, "<< " + DateTime.Now + " || 4 >>"); //server can see it only from the first thread
ConsoleWriteLine(f1, "<< " + DateTime.Now + " || 5 >>"); //server can't see it
Console.WriteLine("device ip length - " + deviceIp.Split('*').Length);
serial_number = deviceIp.Split('*')[0];
android_version = deviceIp.Split('*')[1];
if (network_type == false)
{
    proxy_link = deviceIp.Split('*')[2];
}
port = 42763 + taskIndex / 5;
ConsoleWriteLine(f1, "<< " + DateTime.Now + " || 6 >>"); //server can't see it
baseURL = "http://" + f1.ip_client + ":";
minorURL = "/";
test = data[taskIndex, 3];
ConsoleWriteLine(f1, "<< " + DateTime.Now + " || 7 >>"); //server can't see it
}

static void ConsoleWriteLine(TestClass f1, string console_message)
{
    try
    {
        f1.ipAddr = new IPAddress(new byte[] { Convert.ToByte(f1.ip_client.Split('.')[0]), Convert.ToByte(f1.ip_client.Split('.')[1]), Convert.ToByte(f1.ip_client.Split('.')[2]), Convert.ToByte(f1.ip_client.Split('.')[3]) });
        f1.localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(f1.ipAddr, 42762);
        f1.socket_sender = new Socket(f1.ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        f1.socket_sender.ReceiveTimeout = 30000;
        f1.socket_sender.Connect(f1.localEndPoint);
        byte[] messageSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("mes!" + console_message);
        int byteSent = f1.socket_sender.Send(messageSent);
        Console.WriteLine("Client sent mes " + console_message);
        byte[] messageReceived = new byte[1024];
        int byteRecv = f1.socket_sender.Receive(messageReceived);
        Console.WriteLine("Client received mes " + console_message);
        string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageReceived, 0, byteRecv);
        try { f1.socket_sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both); } catch { }
        try { f1.socket_sender.Close(); } catch { }
    }
    catch (Exception oe2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(oe2.ToString());
    }
}
```

I have tried to:
-Change architecture of this programm
-Connect from another computer - from my PC everything works fine, but 2 testers get same error